Pre-1980 movie or TV show: enemy agent (?) with an atomic bomb in US port city
Decades ago, during the previous millennium, I saw part of an old movie or TV episode on television in the USA.
I think that I saw it on a black-and-white TV set, and if so, I have no way of knowing whether it was filmed in black and white or color. And that probably means that I saw it before 1980 at the latest, and it might have been decades old when I saw it.
It was set in what seemed to be a United States port city. Everyone spoke English, but if it was produced in an English-speaking country, the actors would speak English even if it was set in a non-English-speaking country.
The main scene I remember is of a roughly middle-aged man in a room with a device that I thought was probably a small atomic bomb. He seemed to be in communication by telephone or radio with the authorities and spoke with a foreign accent. Possibly he was holding the city hostage and talking about his ransom demands. There was a boy, maybe 10 years old, with the man, probably his prisoner, and the boy apparently understood how the bomb worked, because the man complimented his intelligence.
And I think that is all I remember.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mouse_That_Roared_(film)?

@Valorum  No it is not the Mouse that Roared.  I read the book and saw the movie, long ago, probably before seeing those scenes from the movie or tv episode I am trying to identify.

It could be "Panic in the City" (1968).
There are Russian agents building an atomic device in the basement of a building in Los Angeles (a port city). I do not recall a boy with the agents though.
You can watch the full movie on YouTube here:



